Help with colorbox and formating in articles
Solution:
We take each paragraph and the text within it. This text consists of at least one string with attributes.
For example:
textcolor[HTML]{FF0000}{\fcolorbox[HTML]{FFFF00}{FFFF00}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\fontsize{12pt}{14.399999999999999pt}\selectfont 'Here is the text'}}}

This is stored in such a way that it allows for line breaks in the text if it is too long.
Problem:
As seen in the attachment, two problems arise, which are somewhat interconnected:
A. The text does not wrap at all.
B. The text wraps after each new style (as seen in the code above), even though this should only happen at the beginning of a new paragraph.
Question:
How can one enable line wrapping within a colorbox/fcolorbox without causing wrapping "all the time"? Or is there an alternative that would work better?
My issue as code :
    \documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\newenvironment{customparagraph}[5]
{
\vspace{#1}
\setlength{\leftskip}{#2}
\setlength{\rightskip}{#3}
\begin{spacing}{#4}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-#2-#3\relax}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{left}}{\raggedright}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{center}}{\centering}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{right}}{\raggedleft}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{justify}}{\justifying}{}
}
{
\end{minipage}
\end{spacing}
}

\newcommand{\breakablebox}[1]{%
  \textcolor[HTML]{FF0000}{%
    \fcolorbox[HTML]{FFFF00}{FFFF00}{%
      \mbox{%
        \fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont
        #1%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}




\begin{document}
\begin{customparagraph}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{1.15}{left}
\textcolor[HTML]{FF0000}{\colorbox[HTML]{FFFF00}{{\fontsize{12pt}{14.399999999999999pt}\selectfont Das ist eine lange Zeile, welche bestimmte Stile so einsetzt, dass sie aktuell ueber das ende der Seite ragen sollte, also wenn man das lesen kann, dann ist man gluecklich und der Test Funktioniert (:}}}


\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{\fcolorbox[HTML]{ffffff}{ffffff}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\fontsize{10.00pt}{12.0pt}\selectfont Weiterer Text in dem selben Paragraphen }}}
  
\end{customparagraph}
\vspace{1cm}




\begin{customparagraph}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{1.15}{left}


  \textcolor[HTML]{FF0000}{%
    \fcolorbox[HTML]{FFFF00}{FFFF00}{%
      \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
        \fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont
        Das ist eine lange Zeile, welche bestimmte Stile so einsetzt, dass sie aktuell über das Ende der Seite ragen sollte, also wenn man das lesen kann, dann ist man glücklich 
      }%
    }%
  }

  \textcolor[HTML]{000000}{\fcolorbox[HTML]{ffffff}{ffffff}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\fontsize{10.00pt}{12.0pt}\selectfont Weiterer Text in dem selben Paragraphen }}}
  \end{customparagraph}

  \begin{customparagraph}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{1.15}{left}
    \textcolor[HTML]{FF0000}{\colorbox[HTML]{FFFF00}{\fontsize{12pt}{14.399999999999999pt}\selectfont kurzer Text}}
    \textcolor[HTML]{000000}{\colorbox[HTML]{00ff00}{\fontsize{14.00pt}{16.8pt}\selectfont consequat}}
    
    \textcolor[HTML]{FF0000}{\colorbox[HTML]{FFFF00}{\fontsize{12pt}{14.399999999999999pt}\selectfont langer Text das ist Bljhgggggggggggggggjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjkhghjgjkhgindtext agen}}
    \textcolor[HTML]{000000}{\colorbox[HTML]{00ff00}{\fontsize{14.00pt}{16.8pt}\selectfont consequat}}

    \breakablebox{Das ist eine lange Zeile, welche bestimmte Stile so einsetzt, dass sie aktuell hjfghfhgjfgfhgfhgfhgfhgfhgfhgf fghfdgfhgf fhgfhgfhjg gfhgfh gfhg ghf ghf ghf}
    \textcolor[HTML]{000000}{\colorbox[HTML]{00ff00}{\fontsize{14.00pt}{16.8pt}\selectfont consequat}}

  
    \textcolor[HTML]{000000}{\fcolorbox[HTML]{ffffff}{ffffff}{\fontsize{10.00pt}{12.0pt}\selectfont Weiterer Text in dem selben Paragraphen }}
      
    \end{customparagraph}
\end{document}



Have a look at the lua-ul package. It can highlight text including line breaks.

Note: \fbox, \fcolorbox, \colorbox, \makenbox, and \mbox are horizontal boxes. Inside horizontal boxes you need an explicit vertical box like a \parbox, minipage, tabular and similar, to provide line breaks. So everything in your example is as expected. Please read a LaTeX introduction for more information about boxes.

It's not clear what you intend here, you defined customparagraph as a parbox to allow linebreaks but you put all the content Into colorbox which is like mbox so prevents  line  breaks
